# Will this increase my reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

So far, I've used Stackoverflow in a read-only manner.  I try to search long and hard before asking a new question (and I usually find answers without the need to ask new questions).  But I would like to be able to upvote answers, and don't feel like searching for other questions to answer just to gain enough reputation points to upvote.  Will this question give me enough reputation to do this?  (The answer to this question might be kind of meta).

Comment: Yes, a question will increase your reputation by 5 points for each upvote. However, seeing as it is off topic and will get migrated to meta (or closed) the next reputation recalc will eliminate those points. See [How does "Reputation" work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for more.

Comment: The answer to this question is definitely meta... and probably belongs on meta... and my guess is that it will gain you a mix of up and down votes with down votes probably being slightly more.

Comment: But if this bootstraps my quest for the 15 reputation points I need to upvote, then I will be able to gain further reputation points via upvoting :)

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding something I misunderstood too when I was new.  **You don't gain rep from upvoting.**  You gain it from *being upvoted*.

Comment: this is a sneaky way of getting rep by asking a question if asking a question will increase rep! :)

Comment: Looks like I went up 2 points on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Note that you can also get reputation by _editing_, so even if you don't have any new content to contribute, you can get reputation for improving what's already here. (As long as your edits are good enough to be accepted by the community).

Comment: "don't feel like searching for other questions to answer". Then you're kinda missing the point of SO. Your questions have already been answered? Great! Then contribute some answers to other people's questions.

Comment: @hammar editing questions is a good way to gain rep plus at least for me forced me to read other questions/answers which in turn helps see how to properly answer and ask questions on the sites.

Comment: @Herbert No, I don't think I was missing the point. The whole point of this question was that I wanted to contribute to SO in the way that I wanted: by upvoting answers that I thought deserved upvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your question is now on *Meta* Stack Overflow and its reputation is not tied to Stack Overflow you will not get any reputation that adds to your Stack Overflow reputation. However, you might get reputation on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10):

This is a give and take community. You need to answer, and ask questions in order to gain your reputation. You aren't given all of the privileges immediately because that would take away the nature of how the site works.

Everyone wants a higher [reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), but you have to put in the effort to get it.

But to answer your question, asking and then accepting answers will improve your rep. Plus, if you answer questions other people can boost your reputation, if your answer is good.

Comment: I might shoot for lower, but unfortunately 1 is the floor :(

Answer (score -1):

If you get upvoted, then certainly it will increase your reputation :)

On the other hand, if you get downvoted, it will *decrease* your reputation.

Comment: not if the OP gets downvotes, then reputation will be lost

Comment: Since the question is now on *Meta* Stack Overflow it does no longer have the potential of increasing Stack Overflow reputation. However, it has the potential of increasing Meta Stack Overflow reputation.